# How to select 1st and 2nd row instance in SQL table having the same value in another table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, validation

Sample data:

[image]

Output should be:

[image: Output Data]

I want to ask what script in MSSQL I can run to get that kind of output. Hope somebody can help me I'm still new in SQL programming. Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: please provide sample data and structure of both tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE witha row_number():

```
with CTE as
(
select T1.*, row_number() over(partition by USERNAME order by TRANSACTION_TIME) X_ORD
from Table1 T1
)

select distinct 
       A1.USERNAME,
       A1.REGISTRATION_DATE, 
       A2.Transaction_Time as First_X, 
       A2.RELOAD_AMOUNT as First_R, 
       A2.CHANNEL as First_C, 
       A3.Transaction_Time as Second_X, 
       A3.RELOAD_AMOUNT as Second_R, 
       A3.CHANNEL as Second_C
from CTE A1
left join CTE A2
  on A1.USERNAME = A2.USERNAME
  and A2.X_ORD = 1
left join CTE A3
  on A1.USERNAME = A3.USERNAME
  and A3.X_ORD = 2
```

Comment: This solves my question. Thank you so much http://stackoverflow.com/users/2144048/johnhc.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you JohnHC

Comment: Good answer John, but if the person have same name with different registration date, then query showing wrong result.